# Running Adobe Digital Editions on Ubuntu

Tags: adobe

I have tried at least six or seven methods posted over the web. None work.

Tried it on 14 4. 16.4. 17.4. And 19.4 and 19.10
Has anyone found some instructions that a regular user can follow and that are not from 2012 or so.

I found one by Pat David but I'm too dense to understand them.

I use adobe digital editions to borrow library books on my Kobo reader here in Canada. Works great on win7 but not Ubuntu

Comment: Thats supposed to read: Kobo Reader.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19.10 yet.

Comment: Use Calibre instead. It's native and you can find it at the Ubuntu Software.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Usually library books are locked into a proprietary system such as Adobe Digital Editions rather than Calibre. I personally wish this was different...

Comment: It is three years later and I also would like to have a solution for this.